# I'm trying to do a Autorole function for my private Discord JS Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to do an Autorole Function with Discord JS, but the problem is that there I a big Error and I don't know why. That's the code that I used:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(`[${b}:${c}` + member.user.tag + 'ist dem Server beigetreten!');

    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'user');
    member.addRole(role);
    member.send('', Embeds.autorole)
});
```

(I've defined my role in a var)

And the error is:

```
[${b}:${c}]DoomCity#3747ist dem Server beigetreten!
(node:20220) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
(node:20220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.
    at GuildMember.addRole (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:454:38)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\index.js:198:12)
    at Client.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Guild._addMember (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1298:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
(node:20220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20220) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:20220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at D:\FVKR\Desktop\Team Unknown\Discord Bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
(node:20220) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

And i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead` warning, you need to use:

```
var role = member.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === "user");
```

instead of:

```
var role = member.guild.roles.find("name", "user");
```

For the `TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake.`, I think it's because the role wasn't found. Try to add a `console.log` just after the var.

Then, for the `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message` error, it's because you cannot send an empty string. Use:

```
member.send(Embeds.autorole);
```

instead of:

```
member.send('', Embeds.autorole);
```